# Fastest way to read huge volume of data as dataframe from Oracle using Python

Tags: python, oracle, postgresql, greenplum, bulk-load

I need to read huge amount of data from Oracle (around 1 million and 450 columns) and do a bulk load in Greenplum. I am using following approach:

```
import pandas as pd
from psycopg2 import *
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import cx_Oracle
import sqlalchemy
import psycopg2 as pg
import io

engineor = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://xxxx:xxxx@xxxxx:xxxx/?service_name=xxxxx')
sql = "select * from xxxxxx"
enginegp = create_engine('xxxxx@xxxxx:xxxx/xxxx')
connection = enginegp.raw_connection()
output = io.StringIO()
for df in pd.read_sql(sql, engineor, chunksize=10000):
df.to_csv(output, header=False, index=False,mode='a')
output.seek(0)
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.copy_expert("COPY test FROM STDIN WITH CSV NULL '' ", output)
connection.commit()
cur.close()
```

I have been reading the data in chunks:

```
for df in pd.read_sql(sql, engineor, chunksize=10000):
    df.to_csv(output, header=False, index=False,mode='a')
```

Is there a quicker and seamless way to read big tables from Oracle as a dataframe? This method just works, and doesn't seem seamless as connection to Oracle times out or killed by DBA at times, and it runs successfully at times. Seems less reliable given the table size. I need this as a dataframe as I need to load it in to Greenplum later using copy method.

Comment: Does Greenplum support database links and then you could connect Oracle and Greenplum directly and load the data bypassing Python?

Answer (score 1):

Outsourcer was specifically created to do what you are trying to do but it was written in Java.

http://www.pivotalguru.com/?page_id=20

Comment: I was able to get a server for installation. The link provided for SQL Server is no longer working. Also Microsoft seems to support only SQLJDBC 4.1 or higher. Outsourcer looks for 4.0. Is there way to get over this ? Will the jar file 4.0 to 4.1 or vice versa in os_path file work? Or since I just need Oracle, can I just off the requirement for SQL server in some way?

Comment: You can use the newer 4.1 SQL Server driver with Outsourcer but if you are only use Oracle, you don't need the SQL Server jar file at all.

Comment: Thanks, I got it work and generated the UI page. However, I get this error for gpfdist - ERROR: http response code 400 from gpfdist (gpfdist://xxxxxxx:8010/foo#transform=sessions): HTTP/1.0 400 invalid request (unsupported input #transform) (url_curl.c:454) (seg5 slice1 sdw1.gphd.local:1030 pid=419546) (cdbdisp.c:1322)

Comment: What version of Greenplum on you using?  The transform option on gpfdist has been around for a pretty long time.

Comment: Greenplum 4.3.15.0 build 1.

Comment: Transform was in 4.3.15 so that isn't it.  Your ETL server needs to also be running the 4.3.15 loaders (gpfdist) and be accessible by your segment hosts.  Your standby-master is a usually a good choice to run Outsourcer.

Comment: Okay, the option seems to be working through pgAdmin. I believe I got part of the issue. So our DBA has configured gpfdist to work from a specific path in the Unix server. It will pick only files only from that folder by default.  So this is the example folder.. /abc/data. We can store and access files either from that path or any sub-directories (/abc/data/xyz etc.) from that path. Do you recommend moving any of the outsourcer files or folders that needs to be accessed via gpfdist to that path?

Comment: Outsourcer doesn't land files to then be loaded to Greenplum.  Gpfdist reads the data from the Java program and makes that available directly to the segments.  You can try installing outsourcer in /abc/data but I'm not sure if that is the problem.  It sounds like you have a rather unique environment there.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Installing in that path didn't do anything. I believe the problem is with the path. When we run gpfdist in pgAdmin, we mention its path something like this - LOCATION ('gpfdist://<os-server>-to-<gp-server>:8010/book.csv'). The outsourcer code just has os-server name. So I tweaked it a bit to make it like how we use along with 'to' (because it doesn't recognize anything if osserver alone is given), and gave a valid file name in that location instead of foo just to see what happens. It still says file not found.

Comment: There isn't a file named foo.  The "#transform" directive tells gpfdist to look for the yaml file and execute the program to get data.  I don't understand your os-server to gp-server.  The gpfdist location should just have the name of the server running Outsourcer.  It should be a name that all segment hosts can ping and get to through the network.

Comment: The $OSHOME/config.properties file has a config for "osserver" and this is the hostname for your ETL node.  The name you put here must be a host that every segment host can reach through name resolution.  That seems to be your problem.  You entered a value for osserver that your segment hosts can't resolve and/or reach.